# Automatic Resize of jPanel as text is added

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a text game which has buttons. When a button is clicked, text appears. My text appears inside a jPanel, which is inside a jScrollPane. I would like my jPanel to automatically make more vertical space for my lines of text to be added. I have been doing it by hand but it is a lot more time consuming. Is there anyway to do this, or maybe pack a jPanel somehow. I am pretty new to this so if any extra information is needed for you to help me out feel free to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a component that can do this automatically -- a JTextArea. It will automatically enlarge as more text is added.

If you need more specific help or a code example, please post your own small compilable and runnable test example program, and I can try to modify it.

---

You state:

> I don't want to use a JTextArea because I don't want the user to be able to highlight or delete any of the text that was there in the first place.

No problem. Just make the JTextArea non-focusable and non-editable.

> I have been using jLabels which are equal to "" and when a button is pressed, that jLabel is given a new value.

Try something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AddNewLines extends JPanel {
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 15);
   private JButton addLineBtn = new JButton(new AddLineAction("Add Line", KeyEvent.VK_A));

   public AddNewLines() {
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      textArea.setFocusable(false);
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
      textArea.setOpaque(false);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      add(scrollPane);
      add(addLineBtn);

   }

   class AddLineAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int count = 0;
      public AddLineAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (count != 0) {
            textArea.append("\n");
         }
         textArea.append("Line of Text: " + count);
         count++;
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      AddNewLines mainPanel = new AddNewLines();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add New Lines");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a JTextArea because I don't want the user to be able to highlight or delete any of the text that was there in the first place. I have been using jLabels which are equal to `""` and when a button is pressed, that jLabel is given a new value.

Comment: So I have not tested anything with the JTextArea yet (although I will) but is there anyway to change other features like colour of the JTextArea, and also the ability to bold certain areas of text? If so I can probably make it identical to what I already have.

Comment: @MattSpiller Not allowing the user to select the text is a strange requirement, IMHO - Replacing any of our labels with non-editable text components has made many of our customers very happy, as they can now copy a ranges of text from our programs for many different needs.  Can't say I thought it was that useful to begin with, but the users are going nuts...